# Operaciones Matemáticas con sass

Tags: sass

Tengo un archivo en `sass` y estoy intentando darle un estilo al `.contenedor` de mi pagina, lo que quiero es que mi clase `.contenedor` tenga un `min-height` de la altura de la pantalla del dispositivo menos el alto en pixeles del navbar que es de 50px

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
.contenedor{
    min-height: (100vh - 50px);
    background: url("../images/Fondo.png") fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto no lanza ningún error de compilación pero tampoco hace lo que deseo.
¿quien sabe como obtener la altura de la pantalla del dispositivo y restarle 50px?

la idea es evitar que salga la barra de scroll vertical

Comment: Podrias añadir el resultado que estas logrando?, sea a traves del codigo CSS generado o bien de screenshots.

Comment: Claro ya lo agrego

Comment: Bueno ya lo logre aun que lo hice de otra manera 
aun me interesa como hacer esto 100vh - 50px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En SASS no puedes hacer eso por dos razones:

1. No puedes hacer cálculos en tiempo real, SASS compila y te devuelve un archivo CSS, no tienes acceso al HTML desde SASS.
2. No puedes mezclar unidades distintas en las operaciones matemáticas en SASS.

Sin embargo puedes hacer algo en CSS con la funcion `calc()`. Esta función te permite hacer cálculos en tiempo real y manejar diferentes unidades (probado en Firefox, Chrome e IE11):

```css
.contenedor{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px );
    background: #ccc;
    border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, architecto, voluptatum? Sequi error saepe praesentium accusamus, illo eius minima nobis aliquid perferendis magni, quo quaerat quam unde, ad minus ipsam.</div>
```

**PD:** Por supuesto que puedes usarlo en SASS ya que admite sintaxis CSS y al compilar te devolverá la propiedad tal cual, sin hacer la resta.